# Rails: Statistic

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, statistics

Hi I am new to programming and rails, and I am trying to create an admin interface in my app that shows stats. I have a `Job` model that has many `Responses`, and I need to collect the average response time for each day. In order to collect the response time for the first job I would do the following

```
job = Job.first
response = job.responses.first
response_time = response.created_at - job.created_at
```

This is very simple, but I am having trouble trying to collect this information for all the jobs of that day. Im trying to come up with a solution that will give me an array of data pairs. For example {[June 17, 51s], [June 18, 60s], [June 19, 38s], ... etc}.

I cant seem to figure out the correct rails active record call that will give me what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you are going to find an active record solution, but you have what you need, just need to add a little ruby.

Probably a 100 ways to do it, here is one way that creates a hash with the number of whole days from the job creation date as the key and the count as the value

```
job = Job.first
start_date = job.created_at
response_dates = job.responses.pluck(:created_at) #creates an array of created_at datetimes
day_stats = response_dates.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |dt, h| h[((dt - start_date)/1.day).round(0)] += 1 }
```

This basically iterates through the datetime array, subtracts the response date from the job date, divides it by 1 day and rounds it to a whole day.

Output would be something like:

```
=> {0=>1, 5=>2, 6=>1, 7=>2, 9=>1, 31=>1, 37=>6, 40=>1, 42=>3, 44=>1, 59=>32, 60=>59, 61=>2, 64=>1, 65=>2, 78=>168, 97=>39, 93=>2, 110=>1, 214=>1}
```

If you want the date, you could add the key*1.day to the start_date